# Firebase Realtime Database Data Model Class Problem Kotlin

Tags: database, firebase, kotlin

I cant create data model for this database.

[Firebase Realtime Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXf0l.png)

I can't list chats with this model.

```
data class ChatModel(   var voice : String ?= null,
                        var sender : String ?= null,
    )
```

Example JSON

```
 D/Log: DataSnapshot { key = J7AW1EgBx3cyP4eXfxYIBIfoT2J3, value = 
{33447543={voice=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/xxx.appspot.com/o/33447543.aac?alt=media&token=16e1f68b-2e2d-4c2b-976e-c30bdc38012d, chatwith=etcmobileapps, sender=mesut@gmail.com}, 32190281={voice=etcmobileapps.com, chatwith=etcmobileapps, sender=etcmobileap@gmail.com}} }
```

If I remove the chatwith value, chat messages appear on my screen, but not with chatwith.

I need data class model for chatwith and chats messages.

Comment: What's wrong with the existing data model?

Answer (score 0):

In your realtime database structure, you have sibling nodes with different structure. There is no straightforward way to convert that to a POJO/data class.
Probably the easiest solution is to restructure your realtime database and put all the chat messages under a new node. Something like this:

```
chats
  |---J7AW1.....
          |---messages
                 |---32190281
                       |---sender: 
                       |---voice:
                 |---33447543
                       |---sender: 
                       |---voice:
          |---chatwith:
```

Then your `ChatModel` will be:

```kotlin
data class ChatModel(
    val chatwith: String? = null,
    val messages: List<ChatMessage>? = null
)

data class ChatMessage(
    val sender: String? = null,
    val voice: String? = null
)
```